# Need to execute a linux bash script only once during the life time of the server

Tags: linux

I have a linux script at certain location and this script need to be executed just once at the life time of the server. post the server build is over and it comes online the script need to be executed.

i have the script at /tmp am trying to see cron and at. dono which one can help here. I am sure cron cant do it. any suggestion does any one have. ?

Thanks

Raj

need to execute a script at the boot time of the server

Comment: why not have the bash script rm itself at the end

Comment: Create an systemd unit file, and enable it on boot using `sudo systemctl enable <name.service>`. So everytime your boot your server it will execute it for you. Or you can add an execution command in /etc/profile file.